# "Soundness in body" vs "Soundness in the body"

Tags: definite-articles

Which one of the following is correct?

> Soundness in body is abundance in itself

or

> Soundness in the body is abundance in itself

Comment: Why do you think either is incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct, but the usual expression is *soundness **of** body*.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you normally see the article omitted when speaking of *soundness of mind*, but you might see it inserted when speaking of *soundness of (the) body*.  Not sure why this is, but that seems to be the way it is:

[image]

[image]